# Selenium Webdriver and Firefox Server Not Found error

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Win 7 64, Selenium IDE 2.5.0, WebDriver 2.42 and Eclipse Kepler SR2.
I'm trying to launch the browser using driver.get but no matter what URL I put, I get the browser opening but with Server Not Found error.
It is driving me crazy.
It looks like it opens an instance of Firefox that doesn't look like the one I use to navigate Internet, it doesn't have my bookmarks and my addons and doesn't connect to Internet.
Any help?
Thanks.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa
public class NavigateToAUrl {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver () ;
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why such outdated Selenium? Upgrade and try again.

Comment: Selenium 2.5.0 is the latest available, why you are saying that it is outdated?

Comment: latest is 2.42 http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: Oh yeah, Webdriver is 2.42, the IDE is 2.5.0.

Comment: So the problem was that the loading of a working Firefox profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile", "default");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://google.com/");
```